# Pandas: Use selected amount of previous rows in apply function

Tags: python, pandas

lets say I have dataframe below:

```
index  value 
 1       1
 2       2
 3       3
 4       4
```

I want to apply a function to each row using previous two rows using "apply" statement. Lets say for example I want to multiple current row and previous 2 rows if it exists. (This could be any funtion)

Result:

```
index  value  result 
 1       1     nan 
 2       2     nan 
 3       3      6
 4       4      24
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need `df['value'] * df['value'].shift() * df['value'].shift(2)` ?

Comment: See myon edited answer below. Happy to help further le me just know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `rolling` with `prod`:

```
df['result'] = df['value'].rolling(3).apply(lambda x: x.prod())
```

Output:

```
   index  value  result
0      1      1     NaN
1      2      2     NaN
2      3      3     6.0
3      4      4    24.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use assign function:

```
df = df.assign(result = lambda x: x['value'].cumprod().tail(len(df)-2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have more than four rows. If so, please try `groupby` `every four rows`, `cumproduct`, choose the `last 2` and `join` to the original datframe.

```
df['value']=df.index.map(df.assign(result=df['value'].cumprod(0)).groupby(df.index//4).result.tail(2).to_dict())
```

If just four rows then this should you;

Lets try combine `.cumprod()` and `.tail()`

```
df['result']=df['value'].cumprod(0).tail(2)



 index  value  result
0      1      1     NaN
1      2      2     NaN
2      3      3     6.0
3      4      4    24.0
```